# 'Cant read property of undefined' error in Twitch API response

Tags: jquery, json, twitch, twitch-api

I am trying to display all `display_name` values of this JSON page (the max is 25), however I get an error of "cant read property of undefined". My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url= "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows?client_id=40pbvj5imeg5ma36gla9p8ryfkyyyb&limit=100";
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(string, field) {
        // $.each(string, function(k, v) {
        $("#fccStatus").append(string.follows.user + " ");
        // });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's two issues. Firstly you need to iterate over `result.follows`, not `result`. Secondly, the `string` argument is actually the integer index of the current object in the array. You need to use `field` instead. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows?client_id=40pbvj5imeg5ma36gla9p8ryfkyyyb&limit=100";
  
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
      $.each(result.follows, function(i, field) {
        $("#fccStatus").append('<p>' + field.user.display_name + '</p>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>
<div id="fccStatus"></div>
```

Note that I changed the output HTML to show the user's `display_name` wrapped in `p` elements for clarity, but this can be easily amended if needed.